# how to implement a jruby authentication script for ZAP security proxy

Tags: ruby, authentication, jruby, zap

my question is about script based authentication in ZAP security proxy.
I try to use ZAP security proxy for testing a hybris application. Unfortunately, I am not able to login into the application by using the default authentication methods or the zest scripting. I found the ruby extension to implement ruby code, but I am not sure how this works.
I created a new login script as you see here:
[add_login_script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1A88.png)
Afterwards a get predefined jruby code, but I don't get to work with that. There is a helper class definition in the authenticate method. Where can I find this? Where do I get the params from?
If I like to load the script to the session properties, I get the following error:[load_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvtUz.png)

Even if I declare a method called getLoggedInIndicator(), I get this error message.

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

We have some example scripts here: https://github.com/zaproxy/community-scripts/tree/master/authentication

They are all javascript ones, but the classes will be the same. If you have updated your ZAP add-ons then you'll get code completion on the main parameters.

For more help I'd suggest using the ZAP Scripts group: http://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-scripts